# IntelliJ is clearing helpful log info on debug error

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ is deleting helpful println and error messages on Debug mode error.

It clears the Debug console and leaves me with:

```
Execution failed for task ':AutoAuth.main()'.
> Process 'command '/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: Does it run from the command line Gradle? [Disabling delegation](https://i.imgur.com/HpeUaUE.png) may help.

Comment: Disabling delegation fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the root case of the problem is not clear as the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) was not provided, there are several things that can be done to workaround this issue:

1. See if it runs from the [command line Gradle](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-run-java-main). If it does run, the issue is probably with the JDK or with the way IDE is generating the Gradle script to start it. If it fails, the issue is probably system specific or some wrong Java VM options are used.
2. JetBrains Runtime bundled with IntelliJ IDEA is not designed for development. As [described in the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html), you should download and install your own JDK to compile and run the apps.
3. By default IntelliJ IDEA will build and run using Gradle, but this can be changed back to IntelliJ IDEA build/run configurations:

[image: No delegation]